# loop is not breaking

Tags: python, input, keyboard

So my code has a loop for checking if the key "q" is pressed.
When so then it executes the function if a other key than q is pressed it should break the loop right?

```
def loopclick():
    for i in range(1000000000000000):
        mouse.position = (statmovrestaurantposX, statmovrestaurantposY)
        sleep(0.2)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        clickdoc() # bewegt zeiger zu doc und clickt ihn 
        clickconfirm() # bewegt Zeiger zu confrim und clickt 
        clickrestart() # bewegt zu restart und clickt

def runbot():
    while True:
        try:
            if keychecker.is_pressed('q'):
                loopclick()

                break
            else:
                pass
        except:
            break
```

Comment: Did you debug and see?

Comment: It should loop forever if q is not pressed,unless `keychecker.is_pressed` raises in that case. If q is pressed, it looks like it will be stuck in `loopclick` for at least ~ 6.3e6 years (based on the sleep calls, assuming the argument is seconds), before returning so the break can be hit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is your use of the `sleep()` function. That function will make your program unresponsive while it is executing, and if a loop takes 0.23 seconds of which 0.2 seconds the program is unresponsive you would need to send the input during the remaining 0.03 seconds (i.e. spamming "q"). It's hard to tell if this is the error though, because you have several other functions that we don't know what they are doing...

Comment: I believe that this is likely the problem. The loop is going to last for millions of seconds (if not more), so it would seem like the `while` loop isn't breaking when in reality the `loopclick()` function just hasn't run its course.